# Javascript variable is undefined but it is defined

Tags: javascript

I've this method in my global controller object of my JavaScript application. Now I get the error, that the statement *self.texts.buttons.disabledFinishedJobs* is undefined. But I don't understand that because the *console.log()* statement outputs the expected value. What can be the reason?

```
toggleFinishedJobs: function() {

        var self = this;
        console.log(self.texts.buttons.disabledFinishedJobs[0]);
        if (this.disabledFinished) {
          $(".status_99").show();
          this.disabledFinished = false;
          $("btn_finishedJobs").text(self.texts.buttons.disabledFinishedJobs[0]);
        } else {
          $(".status_99").hide();
          this.disabledFinished = true;
          $("btn_finishedJobs").text(self.texts.buttons.disabledfinishedJobs[0]);
        }

      }
```

Comment: what exactly is the error message and in which line ?

Comment: Which line is the browser indicating you have something undefined? What is the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: I'm guessing there's no element matching this `$("btn_finishedJobs")`, it's probably either an ID or a class

Comment: Typo: In the last `disabledFinishedJobs`, `Finished` is lowercase rather than capitalized.

Comment: Don't doubt the error message. Use the debugging tools available in the browser, and inspect the *actual* values for the relevant expressions when the exception is raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("btn_finishedJobs").text(self.texts.buttons.disabledFinishedJobs[0]);
                                                      ^-Typo error
```

instead of

```
$("btn_finishedJobs").text(self.texts.buttons.disabledfinishedJobs[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo at the end of your code. `self.texts.buttons.disabledfinishedJobs` instead of `self.texts.buttons.disabledFinishedJobs`.